# Read text from file and style specific words and display in RichTextBox in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, richtextbox

I'm trying to create as a challenge for myself a text editor with some simple syntax features.(Like display some specific words in bold, different color, etc.).

I'm using Windows forms and Visual C++ and this is what i've done so far:
- i've opened, read the file in a String^ and displayed it in the RickTextBox;
- i've managed to style the desired words only with Find() method as seen in the stylewords() method in code sample;

My goal would be to open and read the file in a String^, check and compare each word if it is going to be individually styled and after i have applied the style rules i will load the text in the richTextBox.

/* this is loading the document in the RichTextBox control */

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Stream^ myStream;
             OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1=gcnew OpenFileDialog;
             if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog()==System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
             {
                 if((myStream=openFileDialog1->OpenFile())!=nullptr)
                 {
                     String^ strfilename=openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1->FileName;
                     String^ Readfile=File::ReadAllText(strfilename);
                     //MessageBox::Show(strfilename);
                     richTextBox1->Text=Readfile;
                     myStream->Close();
                 }
             }
             stylewords(); //call method to style words
         }
```

I know i can use the Find() method to search for a specific word and apply a style to it but from what i know this works searching the whole string for that exact word and if i want to style let's say another 10 more different words i must do that over and over again....

```
void stylewords(){
int index=0;
while (index<richTextBox1->Text->LastIndexOf(textBox1->Text)) {
    richTextBox1->Find("abcdef", index, richTextBox1->TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds::WholeWord);
    richTextBox1->SelectionFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Tahoma", 16, FontStyle::Italic);
    richTextBox1->SelectionColor=Color::DarkBlue;
    richTextBox1->Find("xyz", index, richTextBox1->TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds::WholeWord);
    richTextBox1->SelectionFont=gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Tahoma", 16, FontStyle::Bold);
    richTextBox1->SelectionColor=Color::DarkOrange;
    index=richTextBox1->Text->IndexOf(textBox1->Text,index)+1;       
}}
```

Feel free to give advice or point me in the right direction ! 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: As you are using C++/CLI, Microsofts great language that combines the cryptic syntax of C++ with the runtime execution speed of C#, you may want to switch to either language and reap the benefits of C++'s execution speed or C#s ease of use. Using C++/CLI is really only for people who want to use legacy code. If you don't have legacy C++ code, you are better of using either pure C++ or C#.